# Django: format raw query for template when using cursor.execute()

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to perform a raw query:

```
 cursor.execute("select id, name from people")
 results = cursor.fetchall()
```

How do I convert this so that I can use it in a Django template:

```
{% for person in results %}
  {{person.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Normally, I'd use the model:

```
results = people.objects.raw("select id, name from people")
```

That works regardless of how many other models/tables I use in the query.

However, that method requires that I include the primary id for the people model. I cannot do that this time because the sql is actually a `group by` query, and cannot contain the id.

I definitely want to use raw sql, not some other way of doing the equivalent of "group by".

Comment: What is your actual query which you want to perform? May be it can be possible to do it via django ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. Converts the tuple of tuples into a list of dictionaries and gets the field description from cursor.description. Could be made as a little function. And there's probably some smart lamdba thing that could make it shorter.

```
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(my_select)
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        x = cursor.description
        resultsList = []   
        for r in results:
            i = 0
            d = {}
            while i < len(x):
                d[x[i][0]] = r[i]
                i = i+1
            resultsList.append(d)

        return render_to_response(my_template, {"results":resultsList})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist that you need to perform raw sql query using MySQLdb cursor, then create a dictionary cursor [DictCursor](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html), so that column values can be accessed by name rather than by position.

```
 cursor.close ()
 cursor = conn.cursor (MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
 cursor.execute ("SELECT id, name FROM people")
 results = cursor.fetchall ()
 for row in results:
     print "%s, %s" % (row["id"], row["name"])
```

Using `DictCursor` you don't need to do any thing just pass it to the template and use it the same way you do with the django queryset.

Comment: This isn't working. Seems like you have to provide the MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor parameter in connect(), not cursor(). But I'm using Django to do do the connection automatically. btw, this requires import MySQLdb

Comment: This was for `MySQLdb` cursor not for django db cursor.

Comment: But then I'd have to do the connectionm supplying password, etc.? I like that Django does that for me.